# How to Fetch Rss Feeds From Other Websites

Tags: rss, feed

I've 3-4 Blogs 2 on same topics 
I want if i post on 1st blog
then 2nd blog can fetch feeds automatically and save that in database as a post

or Can anyone tell me how smashing network work
when someone post in his blog smashing fetch feeds and excerpt and show it in smashing network and when user click on that post he/she redirect to original blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something free I use [FeedWordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) on one of my site which works well. There is also a commercial plugin [AutoBlogged](http://autoblogged.com/). These are the two I know of, I'm sure others exist.

Comment: Okay That Plugin is Really Great I checked out now and get code by opening files thanks

Comment: Which one? Also, if it works out for you don't forget to make this answer :)

Comment: FeedWordpress I don't believe in waste money in scripts

Comment: I already up voted you :)

Comment: @MohitBumb An up vote simply suggest that the answer is a good answer. If you check the check mark next to the question it means the answer SOLVES the problem (or best solves it) This helps others know it's the correct answer.  Also we won't get into the advantages of paying for software :)

Comment: ok ok done now...